# How can I make the linux time function prefix the output of a command insteading of placing the output after the command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
~$ /usr/bin/time -f "%e: " echo test
test
0.00:
```

I want the output to be

0.00: test

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You don't know how long the command took until after it's performed all of its output.

Comment: /usr/bin/time -f "%e: " echo test >so 2>se; echo $(<se) $(<so)

Works.  He redirected to file descriptor.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you're asking for some form of time travel, you would need to capture the output and rearrange it.  `time` outputs its result on standard error.

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%e: " echo test >so 2>se; echo $(<se) $(<so)
0.01: test
```

Comment: How would I do this in a make file? I wanted to wrap "CXX = g++"

Comment: That's actually a rather different question, as `g++` will send any output (since it only produces output on error) to `stderr`.  It's complex enough that you would want to use a wrapper script.  Also, are you thinking of wrapping the (normally nonexistent) output from `g++`, or the echoed command from `make`?  The latter can't easily be done while echoing the actual command.

Comment: Anything.  I just realized that the output was not from gcc, but from the make file.  You are correct.  When it is compiling main.cpp it outputs "main.cpp", how would I do "0:04: main.cpp", something like that?

Comment: That's more complicated, as the macro doesn't have ready access to the filename you want to echo; you need to replace the `make` pattern rules.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules for `gmake`; it's similar for other versions of `make` although specific details will differ.

Answer (score 1):

As geekosaur's answer says, time prints to stderr, and your command prints to stdout.  And time waits for your command to finish before writing its output.  I think you should try the program `sponge` from the package [`moreutils`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/), like this:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%e: " echo test | sponge
```

Sponge is a program which soaks up all the input and writes it when the input is closed (i.e. the previous program terminates).  The above works because time will print to stderr when echo finishes, and echo's stdout will be soaked up by the sponge, which will only wring itself out when the left hand side finishes.  So this does pretty much what you want as far as I can tell, though I wasn't able to test it for complete accuracy because my system's /usr/bin/time doesn't support the -f option.

Comment: Our build system might freak out if it sees sterror.

Comment: You can add redirection to stdout at the end:
`(/usr/bin/time echo test | sponge) 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible.  One way of doing it is to capture the output into a variable and manipulate it.

Comment: I did not ask whether it was possible, I asked how to do it.